# Using results from refereed papers

Tags: discussion, etiquette

If a question pops up which is answered by a theorem inside some paper I’ve refereed that isn’t in print yet, is it appropriate to answer the question and cite the (presumably) forthcoming paper or should I contact the authors and offer them the opportunity to answer/wait until it’s published then answer and cite the official publication?

Comment: Is the preprint on the arXiv?

Comment: When sent to you for refereeing, the manuscript should be considered confidential.  If the preprint is available for some other reason, then go ahead and cite it.

Comment: You can probably find a bunch of somewhat related questions on Academia. For example: [May I discuss a paper I have only seen as a referee?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/72973) or [How to use results/ideas from a paper I reviewed?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/72180)

Comment: @ToddTrimble This was asked out of general concern rather than a specific case, but the arXiv does seem like a good barometer.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Got it, much appreciated.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for the links, I'll snoop around over there next time I have a question of this nature.

Comment: Note that now it's easy to deduce you are the referee, even if you refer to the arxiv version. :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'll be holding my tongue (or fingers as it were) on this one regardless, but good call. :)